# Why concurrent modification exception is thrown?

Tags: java, collections

I know that concurrent modification exception is thrown when the collection is structurally changed while iterating it, but why?

what are the potential problems if we don't throw concurrent modification exception?
how concurrent modification exception prevents undetermined behaviour in future?
if its because to prevent multithreading related issues why its also thrown when the same thread which called the iterator modifies the collection structure?

this may be a pretty basic question but I do need some proper scenario to convince myself that checking **ConcurrentmodificationException** is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Suppose you store a 5 at the end of your collection, then your are happily iterating through your collection and when you reach the end... boom there's a 4. Wouldn't it be good to know what happened, when it happened (fail-fast)? Basically if we don't notify that something happened, you will get what appears to be random bugs at random times, good luck fixing those.

Comment: also may i know why downvotes to my question ?i think its a genuine doubt that needs to be addressed. if you think this is duplicate please post the question. thanks

Comment: "to convince myself that checking ConcurrentmodificationException is absolutely necessary." Oh no, checking for CME is absolutely *unnecessary*. Doing anything with it other than letting the programming error it indicates show up, well, hides the programming error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not "absolutely necessary", but it helps prevent a number of potential bugs, both in single-threaded and multi-threaded code. Suppose for instance you're iterating over a set and add or remove an element - how should the iterator handle that? There isn't an obviously correct behavior (you might want it to appear later in the iteration, or you might not).

To avoid CMEs you'll generally want to use two separate collections - one you iterate and one you mutate. This also often leads to cleaner code that's easier to reason about. In the specific case of lists you can iterate over the indices (`for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)`) but you need to be careful about how `i` changes when you modify the list so you don't skip or double-iterate over an element.